# What is the best way to determine WinAPI minimum supported client for a program?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, requirements

I'm using Visual C++ and Windows API.
On MSDN, each function's description page has a **requirements** section that shows **minimum supported client** (as in the example below; CreateFile function).

[image]

Do I have to manually check each Win32 function in my program in order to determine the minimum supported client or is there an automatic way?

Comment: Or accept that anything from Windows XP upwards is de-facto, as WinAPI's never change mostly.

Comment: You pretty much need to know which functions you are calling. Defining WINVER and related conditionals is one way to make sure you don't use functions that aren't available in your minimum supported version. Decide this before you start coding, not after you have finished. Testing is also important.

Comment: @t0mm13b not exactly; I've seen several functions with Vista or 8 as the minimum client. GetActiveProcessorCount function comes from Windows 7, for instance.

Comment: I said *mostly* it is your responsibility to conditionally compile in calls to api's to cater for more recent Windows.

Comment: You can't always trust what "Minimum supported client" says. There are tons of APIs on MSDN that lie about that value, things that have been available since W2K/XP but now say Vista/Win7/8 instead. The key word is **supported** here. When Microsoft drops support for a given Windows version, MSDN tends to drop that version from most docs, including the "Minimum supported client" field of most (not all) existing APIs. It would be nice if API docs had an "Added in Version" type of field (that is what "Minimum supported client" was *supposed* to be) that doesn't change over time, but they don't

Comment: Set the windows version macros and build for Windows 7 since Vista is no longer supported.  You should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would actually test your program on the versions of Windows your program supports. If you link directly to a function that does not exist then Windows will display an error message and the program will not run at all.

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot fully trust version information on MSDN. `CreateFile` has existed since Windows 95/Win32S/NT3.x but only `CreateFileA` actually worked on non-NT systems, `CreateFileW` just fails with a "not implemented" error code. If your minimum target is Windows XP or higher then you don't have to worry about the 9x/NT split but you should still test your software to make sure.

You also need to be careful if you change `WINVER` because it can change the size of some structures and then be rejected by certain functions on older Windows versions.

Comment: You seem to have a different recollection than I do. The Win32 *W functions simply didn't exist on W'95, that's why you could have MSLU (MicroSoft Layer for Unicode). It would map the *W functiosn to the *A equivalents.

Comment: @MSalters The W functions from NT3.x are exported on 95 but everything except MessageBoxW and lstrlenW (and possibly a handful more) are simple stubs that fail.